# Proper way for content internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

I am not talking about internationalizing user interface. E.g. "Signup" in English, Chinese, Japanese, Spanish, etc. I'm more into content internationalization.

Let's say I have a website for small business listing. So there is this shop A with the following details in English:

```
id | shop_name | description                            | lang
1  | A         | Saloon for children under 5 years old  | en
```

If I wanna have an option to filter English and Spanish content for my website, and I wanna have a Spanish translation (manually) of shops, I plan to do this:

```
id | shop_name | description                            | lang
1  | A         | Saloon for children under 5 years old  | en
2  | A         | Salón para niños menores de 5 años     | es
```

So then I run a filter in my app based on URL: `http://abc.com/1` for English; `http://abc.com/es/2` for Spanish.

Is this proper? Is there a better way?

By the way, I am building a Ruby on Rails app.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple question and is not specially related to Ruby on Rails. First you should find out if you are going to have a base language that is translated or not to another languages, or if you can really have multilanguage content  (like a page in `es` that does not exist in `en`).

Bases on the above information you can go one way or another, each of them having their own advantages or benefits.